Pandapower Incorrect Transformer Loading Calculation and Impedance Problems
I’m working on a Python-based power flow analysis using the Pandapower library, but I’ve run into some issues related to the diagnostic tool and transformer loading calculations that seem to be linked to potential bugs or misinterpretations within the Pandapower framework.
Project: I’m using Pandapower to model a small distribution network with 16 buses, several lines, and a 0.25 MVA transformer connecting the network to the medium-voltage grid.
Objective: I need to accurately simulate power flow and transformer loading under different load conditions.
Encountered Issues:
A.   -> SOLVED
The network includes a transformer rated at 0.25 MVA (20/0.4 kV). I’ve set up loads across multiple buses and expected the transformer loading to vary with changes in load.
Regardless of significant changes in load (e.g., increasing each house connection load from 0.01 MW to 0.1 MW), the transformer loading percentage remains nearly constant and unrealistically low.
trafo loading results
steps I tried:

Changing the load while having constant transformer: loading changes in the sixth/seventh value after the comma
Changing the trafo while having constant load: different loading value, but not realistically higher/lower in relation to the trafo rated power. Also only 3-4 percent points changing

-> Solved: in the Slack-Sheet of the input-excel the wrong bus was connected (has to be the medium voltage grid bus aka the external grid representative)
**B. ** -> OPEN
pandapower_converter.py:712: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  rx_mag = mag_g / np.sqrt(i_no_load * i_no_load * 1e-4 - mag_g * mag_g)

steps I tried:
I tried to set up a new pandapower file with a small test grid from the pandapower website and then the transformer loading values are changing realistically, but the rx_mag error is still on. I printed i_no_load and mag_g and those are 0.32 and 0.0032 which are 0 when connected through the formula. From the pandapower_converter.py file I know that the rx_mag is "only" used to check the transformer values, and not in further calculations, but it is unnerving either way.
Here the code how the value is used:
# Calculate rx ratio of magnetising branch
        mag_g = np.divide(pfe, sn_mva * 1000, where=valid)
        mag_g[np.logical_not(valid)] = np.nan


        rx_mag = mag_g / np.sqrt(i_no_load * i_no_load * 1e-4 - mag_g * mag_g)
        # positive and zero sequence magnetising impedance must be equal.
        # mag0_percent = z0mag / z0.
        checks = {
            "vk0_percent": np.allclose(vk_percent, vk0_percent) or np.isnan(vk0_percent).all(),
            "vkr0_percent": np.allclose(vkr_percent, vkr0_percent) or np.isnan(vkr0_percent).all(),
            "mag0_percent": np.allclose(i_no_load * 1e-2, 1e4 / (vk0_percent * mag0_percent))
            or np.isnan(mag0_percent).all(),
            "mag0_rx": np.allclose(rx_mag, mag0_rx) or np.isnan(mag0_rx).all(),
            "si0_hv_partial": np.isnan(
                self._get_pp_attr("trafo", "si0_hv_partial", expected_type="f8", default=np.nan)
            ).all(),
        }
        if not all(checks.values()):
            failed_checks = ", ".join([key for key, value in checks.items() if not value])
            logger.warning(f"Zero sequence parameters given in trafo shall be ignored:{failed_checks}")

C.   -> OPEN
I manually input impedance values for the lines using the following parameters:
import pandapower as pp

# Define impedance values
r_ohm_per_km = 0.322097
x_ohm_per_km = 0.073199

# Example line creation
pp.create_line_from_parameters(net, from_bus, to_bus, length_km=0.1, r_ohm_per_km=r_ohm_per_km, x_ohm_per_km=x_ohm_per_km, c_nf_per_km=210, max_i_ka=0.24)

Despite these correct values, Pandapower’s diagnostic tool flags several lines as having impedance values close to zero (r_ohm <= 0.001 or x_ohm <= 0.001). This occurs after running the power flow calculation, although the values remain unchanged in the network model.
steps I tried:
I’ve checked the impedance values immediately after importing them, and they are correctly set in the Pandapower model. The issue only appears after running the diagnostic tool. Additionally, after running the power flow calculation, the values remain correct, but the diagnostic tool still reports the same problem. I found out that when I change the line length the impedance problem doesn't occur, so it has to be some calculation in the background that gets to small, but 15m is not that unusually short. I wonder which code changes could help that.

I’ve used both the old (pp.runpp()) and new (pp.run.runpp_pgm()) power flow calculation functions in Pandapower, with similar results.

request for help:

Is there more options for log files in pandapower?

I am quite new to python programming, is there another option to search for errors?
thank you!


